# How to get base admin Magento url?

Tags: magento, admin

It should be trivial, but cannot find a correct way. 
Even if default is "/admin" I would like not to hardcode as it might change in future.

Obviously, these variants are incorrect:

```
Mage::getUrl('admin');
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('admin');
```

UPD:
It seems some clarification is needed. Right now I have this url to my admin panel:
http://sample.com/admin
but later I might have to change it to
http://sample.com/backend
and would like to keep my link generating code untouched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
Mage::getUrl('adminhtml');
```

Comment: @AntonKolenkov yes, it should work for custom url and custom path

Answer (score 0):

From the following url you will find different way to get Admin specific url http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/magento-getting-the-admin-panel-urls/

Comment: I need a base admin url(like /admin, or whatever it's set to).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Mage::helper('adminhtml');
```